# How can I use negative lookahead to match a subsection of a larger string?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Say I have a list of raw tabular data separated by multiple spaces, and I want to split it into individual columns. Some of the columns can be represented by strings that may have spaces in them, and because the presence of multiple spaces will be how I determine the boundaries between the data in each column, I am trying to use a negative lookahead to match only strings with a single space.

For example, with data like this:

```
  1   123456   This is a test string   ABC-123   0
```

I tried a regex like this:

```
^\s+(\d)\s+(\d+)\s+((?!.*  )[A-Za-z ]+)\s+([A-Z]{3}-\d{3})\s+\d$
```

However it does not work as expected. Intuitively I feel like my usage/understanding of how the lookahead actually operates is not correct (and probably of regular expressions in general), so I'm struggling to pinpoint the exact issue and find the solution.

How can I make this negative lookahead apply only to the `This is a test string` column and use the capture groups to extract data from each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the columns look to all be separated by at least 2 spaces, you can omit the lookahead entirely and just lazily repeat the permitted characters for a column until matching `\s{2,}` (two or more spaces):

```
^\s+(\d)\s+(\d+)\s+([A-Za-z ]+?)\s{2,}([A-Z]{3}-\d{3})\s+(\d)$
#    ^^ g1  ^^ g2   ^^^^^^^^^^^ g3     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ g4  ^^ g5
#                              ^ lazy repeat group 2's chars
```

https://regex101.com/r/V1Wqqs/1

If you wanted to use negative lookahead for this, it'd look kind of messy, but you'd have to match character-by-character, and before each character, negative lookahead for 2 spaces:

```
^\s+(\d)\s+(\d+)\s+((?:(?!\s{2})[A-Za-z ])+)\s{2,}([A-Z]{3}-\d{3})\s+(\d)$
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/V1Wqqs/2

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful as an alternate solution and I may end up accepting it. I am still curious about how the negative lookahead could be used to solve it, though.

Comment: It's possible, but ugly, see edit, I wouldn't recommend it